# How do I hide the square brackets in my template expressions?

Tags: angularjs, templates, expression

I have a simple JSON object in my models

```
whitelist = [
{
    "name": "Whitelist #1",
    "permissions": [
        "production_sdk", 
        "source_sdk", 
        "service"
    ],
},
{
    "name": "Whitelist #2",
    "permissions": [
        "production_sdk", 
        "service"
    ],
},
{
    "name": "Whitelist #3",
    "permissions": [
        "production_sdk", 
        "source_sdk"
    ],
}
]
```

In my html I have `{{ whitelist.permissions }}`, but the HTML displays the values with brackets - `['production_sdk', 'source_sdk']`.

How can I display the HTML so that there are no brackets?

Comment: Depending on the level of customization you want, use `ngRepeat`, or just some JavaScript functions, like `Array.join()` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

`whitelist.permissions` is an array, how do you want that to be displayed in your html?  You should probably create a simple filter that takes an array and outputs what you want, but you could just change your html to do this to get a comma-separated list:

```
{{ whitelist.permissions.join(', ') }}
```

Another option, especially if you want to style each permission, is to use `ng-repeat` and html elements:

```
<span ng-repeat="permission in whitelist.permissions"><span ng-if="$index != 0">, </span>{{ permission }}</span>
```